# How to get an element at a specific index in an Optional List?

Tags: java-8, option-type

```
Optional<List<Long>> optionalList = getList(someInput);
```

How do i retrieve an element from this list?
How to iterate this list?

Comment: if you want to avoid if checks then maybe --> `optionalList.orElse(Collections.emptyList()).forEach(e -> {  ...  });` ?

Comment: how about retrieving an element at index say 5?

Comment: check if there is a value present within the Optional and then do whatever you want with the list. couple of answers already showing you how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unwrap the list and use it like a normal list.

```
List<Long> list = optionalList.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
list.forEach(System.out::println); // process the list 
                                   // e.g. printing its elements
```

If you just want a `forEach(..)` and don't need the list unwrapped.

```
optionalList.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can check if is present

```
if (optionalList.isPresent()) {
    List<Long> myList = optionalList.get();
    // process list present
} else {
    // process not present
}
```

Or keep using optional to access to one of its elements

```
Optional<Long> longAt5 = optionalList.filter(list -> list.size() > 5)
    .map(list -> list.get(5));
```

Comment: also `orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)` I think that `Collections.emptyList` is not that expensive to use a `Supplier` for it

Comment: i tend to prefer method references whenever possible, i missed the ones in `forEach(..)`, changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a value present and then do some logic:

```
optionalList.ifPresent(list -> {
     ...
});
```

As for processing the list, you could do:

```
optionalList.orElseGet(() -> Collections.emptyList()).forEach(e -> {...});
```